# Validación de formato de fecha no funciona laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, laravel, jquery-datepicker

Estoy usando [Validate:date_format de laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-date-format) para validar el formato de un campo fecha de un formulario, el campo debe tener el siguiente formato: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`, estoy usando [datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) para seleccionar la fecha y el formato que necesito en el campo del formulario.

Mi JS de datetimepicker:

```
$('#tiempo_taller').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
            sideBySide: true,
            showTodayButton: true,
            showClear: true,
            showClose: true,
            toolbarPlacement: 'top',
            minDate: new Date()
        });
```

Validación en el controlador:

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
       'nombre_taller' => 'required|max:45',
       'tipo_taller' => 'required|in:teorico,prueba'
       'tiempo_taller' => 'required|date_format:"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"',
       'taller_rutaarchivo' => 'required'
    ])->validate();
```

Al hacer un `dd($request->all())` para verificar los datos que están llegando al controlador, tengo lo siguiente:

```
array:5 [
  "_token" => "dAlgCU2zISWomE1FCix31r3UTiGs4xJZekwhXMKo"
  "nombre_taller" => "Taller de prueba"
  "tipo_taller" => "prueba"
  "tiempo_taller" => "2017-03-21 20:32:22"
  "taller_rutaarchivo" => "ruta1.jpg"
]
```

Efectivamente está llegando bien la fecha al controlador, pero la validación me sale que no corresponde al formato: `El campo tiempo taller no corresponde con el formato YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.`

También lo he intentado sin las comillas dobles: `'tiempo_taller' => 'required|date_format:YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',`

**¿Qué podría estar haciendo mal?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La validación `date_format` de Laravel utiliza como base los formatos de `DateTime::createFromFormat`, los cuales puedes ver en el siguiente enlace: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

El formato que debes usar en Laravel para que encaje con el que estás usando en el datetimepicker es: `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: =O muchísimas gracias, me ha funcionado a la perfección.